# DropDownListFor doesn't display selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to get the drop down list to have my item selected when there is an item, but it never does. I've Googled this and tried many different methods, but they all seem to use a ViewModel containing the list instead of using ViewBag, but I would like to stick to the ViewBag if possible.

My controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(rep.GetItemList(), "id", "type");
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var model = rep.GetItemByID(id.Value);
            if ( model != null )
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.itemID)
    </div>
```

This doesn't have my item selected in the DropDownList, and I've also tried having a list in the ViewBag and then constructing the SelectList in the View, which some posts say should solve the problem:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemID, new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectList, "id", "type", Model.itemID))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.itemID)
    </div>
```

But none of it seems to work. So I was wondering if there is anyone where that is able to spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `itemID` property is set in the model you are passing to the view

```
if (id.HasValue)
        {
            var model = rep.GetItemByID(id.Value);
            model.itemID=id.Value;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: When I get the model from rep.GetItemByID(id.Value); the itemID is always set. But on a different note, this did point out to me that I need to make sure the id that is being used to the the item returns an item. My problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the selected value from the begining since SelectList is immutable.

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(rep.GetItemList(), "id", "type", id );
                var model = rep.GetItemByID(id.Value);
                if ( model != null )
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(rep.GetItemList(), "id", "type");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

In your View use it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList, "Please select...")
```